# How to implement the cross-product transformation in Google's wide-and-deep model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, recommendation-engine

Having read the paper on wide and deep models for recommender systems, I'm interested in trialing something similar. I'm struggling however to conceptualize how the cross-product transformation they used in the paper was done. The tutorial for the DNNLinearCombinedClassifier demonstrates the use of tensorflow.feature_columns.crossed_columns to perform that transformation, however that implementation only makes sense in a one-to-one relationship between the two columns to be crossed (I.E. when creating the crossed column "workclass_x_education",  for each sample in the dataset there is only one value for workclass and one value for education). In Google's paper they say that:

> The wide component consists of  the  cross-product transformation  of  user  installed  apps and impression apps

and additionally that:

> Each example corresponds to one impression.  The label is app acquisition: 1 if the impressed app was installed, and 0 otherwise.

From that I gather that each sample is a single impression and that there's a feature for "impressed app" which details the app that this impression was marketing. In that context, there can't then be a single feature for "installed app", because a user might have hundreds of installed apps at the time of the impression. This is confusing, because the figures in the paper do imply that it is a single feature:

[image]

Should I interpret that "User Installed App" Categorical Feature not as a single feature, but actually as their dataset having a feature-per-app with a binary flag denoting whether the user has that app installed or not, and that to replicate this functionality in tensorflow I'd need to do something like...

```
app_list = ['app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app4', ...]
installed_app_features = ['app1_installed', 'app2_installed', 'app3_installed', 'app4_installed', ...]

impressed_app = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key='impressed_app', vocabulary_list=app_list)

installed_apps = []

crossed_features = []

for app in installed_app_features:
    feature = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key='app', vocabulary_list=[0,1])
    installed_apps.append(feature)
    crossed_features.append(
        tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
            [impressed_app, feature],
            100
        )    
    )
```

...or am I just completely missing something and need to think about this in a different way?

Many thanks in advance for any help offered.

Dan